# How to use react-datepicker <DatePicker /> properly with or without hook functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I'm coding with a React frontend, and while looking for a way to select days on a calendar, I came across a cool react module called `"react-datepicker"`. This does practically everything I need. I'm trying to use the `<DatePicker />` component as seen on the guide website: https://reactdatepicker.com/

What I'm having trouble with is the hook call. I can't seem to find a workaround for this hook call. When a user selects a date on the calendar, the date that is selected is placed as the value in the text-input. The way that this is done is with a hook call as seen in the website.

Now here's my issue. I would like to be able to use the `onChange` function that I've already written (if it's possible) that changes things on the webpage currently. It seems that there is an issue with hook calls being in functions outside the `render()` function call, as I get the error: `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...`, when I try to call the hook inside of my `onChange` function. Is there a work around for changing the text-input value for the DataPicker text input? Here's what my best attempt looks like right now:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react"; 
...
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
...
export class AddEvent extends Component {
...
    onChange = (handleChange) => (e, e2) => {
        if (e2 == null && e != null) {
            this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        } else if (e2 === null && e === null) {
            //The value I really want to show up in the text box is the one set here
            //It can be accessed for this example as this.state.days[0]
            this.setState({ ...this.state, "days": [null]});
            handleChange();
        } else {
            ...
            if ... {
            ...
            } else{
                //The value I really want to show up in the text box is the one set here
                //It can be accessed for this example as this.state.days[0]
                this.setState({ ...this.state, "days": [e] });
                handleChange();
            }
        }            
    }

    render() {
        //The value I really want to show up in the text box is the one in this.state.days[0]
        const minDate = new Date();
        const [aDate, setDate] = useState(minDate);
        const handleChange = date => setDate(date);

        return(
            <div className="mt-4 mb-4">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    ...
                    <div>
                        <label>Choose the Day(s) the Event could/will occur on:</label>
                        <DatePicker name="day1" onChange={this.onChange(handleChange)} minDate = {minDate} dateFormat="mm/dd/yyyy" />
                    </div>
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
...
```

Comment: React hooks are only valid in functional components or custom react hooks, they can't be used in class-based components. Just create normal component state and use a lifecycle method to update it, or convert your component to a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are inclusive functionality restricted only to functional component. You can 'upgrade' your component to functional or just keep all your date on witch change component should be re-rendered in this.state and using this.setState to change it.

i'm not sure that i keep you business logic but you should doing this in that way:

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from "react"; 

import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

export class AddEvent extends Component {
    state = {
      ///you stafff
      miDate : new Date(),
    }

    onChange = (e, e2) => {
       this.state(state => ({...state, miDate: e.target.value}));

        if (e2 == null && e != null) {
            this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        } else if (e2 === null && e === null) {
            //The value I really want to show up in the text box is the one set here
            //It can be accessed for this example as this.state.days[0]
            this.setState({ ...this.state, "days": [null]});

        } else {

              this.setState({ ...this.state, "days": [e] });
        }            
    }

    render() {
        //!!! you can not use hooks in functional component !!!!!
        // const minDate = new Date();
        // const [aDate, setDate] = useState(minDate);
        // const handleChange = date => setDate(date);

        return(
            <div className="mt-4 mb-4">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    ...
                    <div>
                        <label>Choose the Day(s) the Event could/will occur on:</label>
                        <DatePicker name="day1" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} minDate = {this.state.minDate} dateFormat="mm/dd/yyyy" />
                    </div>
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```